# Traer algunos valores del registro anterior en Mysql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Cordial saludo equipo, agradezco su ayuda por favor en el siguiente inconveniente que tengo en Mysql WorkBench:

Tengo una tabla con nombre olímpicos, que tiene los sgtes campos:
Pais, Oro , Plata, Bronce, Total (Campo calculado de la sumatoria (Oro + Plata + Bronce)),

para lo cual tengo el siguiente caso:
Pais           Oro Plata Bronce Total

China Taipéi    1   2      3    6
Colombia        0   1      0    1

Necesito obtener las medallas de Oro, Plata, Bronce y Total del registro, tupla o fila  anterior al país que es Colombia, viendo la tabla anterior, el país anterior  a Colombia es China Taipéi, entonces seria de la siguiente manera, el resultado para Colombia, sería:

```
Pais      Oro   Plata   Bronce  Total
Colombia   1      2       3      6
```

Para lograr esto, he intentado realizar lo siguiente:

```
 SELECT Pais,
           (SELECT Oro FROM olimpicos olant WHERE olant.Oro < olpres.Oro ORDER BY Oro DESC LIMIT 1) as Oro_anterior,
           (SELECT Plata FROM olimpicos olant WHERE olant.Plata < olpres.Plata ORDER BY Plata DESC LIMIT 1) as Plata_anterior,
           (SELECT Bronce FROM olimpicos olant WHERE olant.Bronce < olpres.Bronce ORDER BY Bronce DESC LIMIT 1) as Bronce_anterior
    FROM olimpicos olpres
    WHERE Pais = 'Colombia';
```

Donde se pone un alias a olímpicos con nombre olant (Olimpico anterior), olpres (Olimpico presente),

```
olant.Oro   Olimpico anterior con el registro Oro
olant.Plata Olimpico anterior con el registro Plata
olant.Bronce Olimpico anterior con el registro Bronce
olpres.Oro   Olimpico presente con el registro Oro
olpres.Plata Olimpico presente con el registro Plata
olpres.Bronce Olimpico presente con el registro Bronce
```

Pero me trae mal los registros de Oro, Plata y Bronce, me trae:

```
Pais    Oro Plata   Bronce
Colombia    Null    0   Null
```

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar,

Att. Hernán Martínez

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué versión de MySQL está ejecutando? Con versiones superiores o igual a 8.0.2 (MySQL >= 8.0.2) puede usar las funciones de ventana ([12.21 Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)).

Aquí una opción (puede hacer todos los ajustes necesarios):

```sql
WITH `medallero_olimpico` AS (
  SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      ORDER BY
        `oro` desc,
        `plata` desc,
        `bronce` desc
    ) `posicion`,
    `pais`,
    `oro`,
    `plata`,
    `bronce`,
    `total`
  FROM
    `olimpicos`
), `pais_a_buscar` AS (
  SELECT
    `posicion`,
    `pais`
  FROM
    `medallero_olimpico`
  WHERE
    `pais` = 'pais 1'
)
SELECT
  `pais_a_buscar`.`pais`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`oro`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`plata`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`bronce`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`total`
FROM
  `medallero_olimpico`,
  `pais_a_buscar`
WHERE
  `medallero_olimpico`.`posicion` =
    IF(
      `pais_a_buscar`.`posicion` = 1,
      `pais_a_buscar`.`posicion`,
      `pais_a_buscar`.`posicion` - 1
    )
GROUP BY
  `pais_a_buscar`.`pais`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`oro`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`plata`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`bronce`,
  `medallero_olimpico`.`total`;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0213fccd7e1f900a05eb9880437c6137).